# Signal ECG , collecte & visualize data

Tags: signal-analysis, noise, filter-design, sensor, ecg

I am currently working on a sensor that visualizes an ECG signal and visualizes its data. Its principle is that it has 3 electrodes that must be placed in specific parts of the body .... I would like to know, please, is a sensor can work on some people and not work on others (because I tested it on a lot of people and it never returns the right signal except in one and only one person, I find it very bizzare)

Comment: Either you are doing something wrong or you ECG equipment is broken.

Comment: Not knowing anything about your setup it is impossible to help you / or answer your question.

Comment: Yes I understand.
What can you tell me  please about the fast Fourier transform method because in using it it sends me complex numbers and I do not know exactly what they are referring to and how they are interested.